# python print folder path not the source

Tags: python-3.x

my python script is in ~/bin and I call it to various folders.
The problem is

```
pwd_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(pwd_path)
```

is printing `${HOME}/bin`, but I want the directory name from where it is called.
ANy clue?

Answer (score 0):

`__file__` is the location_file_name of the script itself

to get the working directory:

```
import os
working_directory = os.getcwd()
```